# AAPT2 resources error when processing debug resources

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aapt, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to switch over to AAPT2, and in the process I'm encountering this error with no hints from the error message as to how to fix.

The error occurs when gradle is on the task `processDebugResources`

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is, since the project was building with AAPT1 and there's nothing specifically in the migration guide regarding this. I do have one resource with an emoji in it, and so I have this in my `build.gradle` file:

```
aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters '--utf16' // Allows emoji in XML
}
```

but even if I remove the emoji from the resource, and remove the `aaptOptions` block, the error persists. I've tried doing a clean build multiple times. If it makes any difference, I have a variety of resources, including xml, png, ttf, txt along with a variety of assets, including js, json, proto, and html. Would AAPT2 have an error with any of these?

Also when I run gradle build with stacktrace, I think I get some additional info

```
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to execute aapt
12:40:26.699 [ERROR]`[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:573)`
```

which seems to be implying it has something to do with apk splits, except I'm not using apk splits in my app at all. Furthermore there are many stacktraces which result in the same error, but all of the stacktraces themselves are different.

This is a lot of information, so hopefully it's enough to diagnose, but I'm personally lost and not sure what the cause of this problem is.

Comment: have you added android.enableAapt2=false in your gradle

Comment: @AndroidGeek I don't want to disable Aapt2, I'm trying to find the root cause of this problem so that I can compile the project with aapt2 and get its benefits

Comment: There should be more errors above the ones you posted. They usually start with "Error:" followed by a file path, line number and the error message. Can you post these as well?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Did you tried this,
>
> Go to your

```
gradle.properties
```

> write the below code and Sync your project

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: I don't want to disable Aapt2, I'm trying to find the root cause of this problem so that I can compile the project with aapt2 and get its benefits

Comment: Can you post the whole error you're getting? It should be above the lines you posted and they usually start with "Error:" followed by a file path, line number and the error message. This would help us identify what's happening, without it I'm afraid it's not enough information.